# attributesOfItemAtPath for many files

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have to match thousands of files from a webservice with the files on the disk of the iOS device. Currently I'm doing this in a loop and validating every file on disk with `attributesOfItemAtPath` on the `shared NSFileManager` to check if any files changed in size, but it feels wrong. Maybe looping over every file is the cleanest way, I was still wondering if there's a way to do `attributesOfItemAtPath` for every file in a directory  (as `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`) upfront without harming excessive disk I/O.

The code runs in a loop and then for every file on disk it does:

```
fileAttributes = [_Core.fileMgr attributesOfItemAtPath:savePath error:nil];

if ([fileAttributes fileSize] != [[image valueForKey:@"filesize"] intValue]) {
    ... // the file has changed or is new
}
```

I'm already thinking of caching the last known file-sizes when it comes to re-loading the app through this loop, but I'm still wondering if there's a more efficient way to get attributes of many files in a more *low-level* efficient way.

Finally; this code is not giving me *slowness*. I'm merely wondering if there's a way to rule out excessive disk I/O, as sometimes this script downloads hundreds or thousands of MegaBytes of images and can take a long time and also does many disk-hits. Maybe there's something possible on a very low-level like `NSPathUtilities`? I'd rather cache 2~4MB of memory to cache a list then to hit the disk thousands of times without any added value.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to do the loop whenever you restart the app, but for handling changes as the app is running you can use something like https://github.com/bdkjones/VDKQueue or any other queue system for watching file system events.

I'm not sure what actually changes the files or do you have any way to have a hook, whenever something changes on the device, log the change and then just check against that change set with the server.

Comment: That's a nice take on the matter. I will certainly look into it. It seems VDK requires GCD, but the readme states it explicitly needs OS X. I'll have to test that later today. 7k files checks on an (older) iPad 3 takes about 2 seconds now. This only happens initially or when reloading the app (with an interval timer of 1 hour) so it's not that bad. I'm just really in this nice optimization flow and am trying to win CPU cycles and memory chunks anywhere I can :). 1+ for the tip